# Permission denied: cannot create /dev/null

Tags: ubuntu, github, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've been trying to get the github commit chart hack to work for like a week now.

this one https://github.com/mavrk/github-graffiti

and this one https://github.com/gelstudios/gitfiti

and this one https://github.com/NunoPinheiro/github-contributions-drawer

and a bunch of others ...

They all require running a bash file, which I've never done and don't know how to do. It looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
REPO=Gitfiti
git init $REPO
cd $REPO
touch README.md
git add README.md
touch gitfiti
git add gitfiti
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE=2017-10-24T12:00:00 GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=2017-10-24T12:00:00 git commit --allow-empty -m "gitfiti" > /dev/null
... bunch more commits here ...
git remote add origin git@github.com:MarynaLongnickel/$REPO.git
git pull origin master
git push -u origin master
```

At the moment, running the bash file results in an error:

```
: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null
: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null
: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null
: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null
: Permission deniedgitfiti.sh: cannot create /dev/null
```

so i tried running it one line at a time and see where it breaks. Turned out it was starting at `git pull origin master` which throws an error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
fatal: Invalid refspec 'master?'
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

so i went to investigate that ... and found this page https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/ which says:

"To make sure you are connecting to the right domain, you can enter the following command: `ssh -vT git@github.com` "

and after that didn't work, I came here.

here's the whole error

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh_0.7.0
debug1: no match: libssh_0.7.0
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:secretkeyhereorsomething
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/solarmew/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/solarmew/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: The title has one error message, but you leave your question off with a git/ssh error message. What are we pursuing here?

Comment: @JeffSchaller sorry, i'm just starting to confuse myself here now...  i guess I don't really know if what I'm doing is making any progress towards solving the error in the title. But on the way I'm also getting other errors. So I just don't even know where to start poking anymore :( All I want is to get the bash file to work and make commits to my github repo.

Comment: On the system where you're running the bash file, regarding the /dev/null error, could you provide the output of `ls -l /dev/null` ?

Comment: "crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 10 15:05 /dev/null" ....
what does that mean?

Comment: Perhaps your script has Windows style (CRLF) line endings, so it's actually trying to write to `/dev/null^M`?

Comment: ([ahem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474854/permission-denied-cannot-create-dev-null#comment867443_474856))

Comment: still no luck, unfortunately

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that your script has Windows CR/LF line endings. It's trying to create the device `/dev/null^M` (where `^M` denotes a carriage return to the beginning of the line), and fortunately does not have permission to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Your other problem seems to be that you're not authenticated into GitHub, and are instead trying to make a commit without a logged in account. Attempt to follow this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/, which will show you how to add a passwordless login so you can

The main problem sems to be `git commit --allow-empty -m "gitfiti" > /dev/null` which is the only line which references /dev/null, which should be created by default on most distributions/OSs. What linux/unix are you running currently? It's probably that you have an incompatible operating system or have insufficient rights to even access /dev/ in which case the operating system is kinda bad.

Comment: The tags on the question answer that.

Comment: oh yeah sorry. I think it's just the windows subsystem being a bitch then.

Comment: Actually, no.  Another tip-off is where the `:` appears on the line in the error messages.

Comment: Ah, you're correct